# Appium returns incorrect coordinates with getSize().getHeight() on Android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have some problem with geting element coordinates on android 4.4.2.
Appium GUI returns correct coordinates, but in Java with getSize().getHeight() I am getting incorrect coordinates.

```
System.err.println(element.getSize().getHeight()); // not correct coordinates (expected result * 3)
System.out.println(element.getSize().getWidth()); // all good
System.out.println(element.getSize().height); // all good
System.out.println(element.getSize().width); // all good
```

On Android 6.0 all works awesome.

Mb who knows an alternative method getHeight for android <5?